# SignalR saving / retrieving messages from conversation

Tags: signalr

I'm having problem saving messages in sql DB. I'm using this project 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/732190/Real-Time-Web-Solution-for-Chat-by-MVC-SignalR-H?msg=5059882#xx5059882xx

I'm saving every message in DB when I click the send button.

On the server side on the hub class I have:

```
public void SendMessageToGroup(string userName, string message, int UserID)
{

    if (UsersList.Count != 0)
    {
        var strg = (from s in UsersList where (s.UserName == userName) select s).First();
        MessageList.Add(new MessageInfo { UserName = userName, Message = message, UserGroup = strg.UserGroup, MsgDate = DateTime.Now.ToString() });
        string strgroup = strg.UserGroup;
        //string UserID = strg.UserID;
        saveMessagetoDB(userName, message, DateTime.Now.ToString(), UserID);
        // If you want to Broadcast message to all UsersList use below line
        // Clients.All.getMessages(userName, message);

        //If you want to establish peer to peer connection use below line so message will be send just for user and admin who are in same group
        //***** Return to Client *****
        Clients.Group(strgroup).getMessages(userName, message, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

}
```

And on the client side, I have:

```
 $('#btnSendMessage').click(function () {
       var userName = $('#hUserName').val();
       var UserID = $('#hUserId').val();
       var msg = $("#txtMessage").val();



       if (msg.length > 0) {

           //// <<<<<-- ***** Return to Server [  SaveMessagetoDB  ] *****
           //objHub.server.saveMessagetoDB(userName, msg, msgDate);
           // <<<<<-- ***** Return to Server [  SendMessageToGroup  ] *****
           objHub.server.sendMessageToGroup(userName, msg, UserID);

       }
   });
```

My problem is that I'm not saving the receiverID / username and I don't know where I have to pass it as a parameter. Withou that reveiverID/username I can't retrieve message history between these two users.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not sending message to a receiver but to a group of receivers!  You can save the group name and rebuild the message history between group users.  (not 2 users)

Comment: In this case, the group only contains 2 users maximum.. my problem is that i can't get receiverID every time I send a message

Comment: in my code, when i send message to a specific user, i must have its user id Before i send the message, if i send message to a group of user, i don't need to know user ids inside that group.  (just like whatsapp).  anyway, if there is only 2 users in that group, why don't you store the user id in the signalr Server when the group is created?